# How to test if directive emited an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this simple directive:

```
    ...
    var readyData = {
        caption: ctrl.caption,
        leftValue: ctrl.leftValue,
        rightValue: ctrl.rightValue,
    };

    $scope.$emit($attrs.id + ".ready", readyData); //$scope is directive's scope and not $rootScope
}
```

and I have the following test:

```
describe("Directive: summaryItem", function () {

  // load the directive"s module

      beforeEach(module("summaryItem"));
      it("Should emit the ready event", inject(function ($compile) {
            element = angular.element("<summary-item id=\"summaryItem\"></summary-item>");
            element = $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            var dscope = element.scope();
            spyOn(dscope, "$emit");

            //run code to test
            expect(dscope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("summaryItem.ready");
      }));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Expected spy $emit to have been called with [ 'summaryItem.ready' ] but it was never called.
```

How can I solve this one? Thanks!

**Update**
For @themyth92 request here is the full Directive's code:

```
"use strict";
(function (angular) {
    /**
     * @ngdoc directive
     * @name summaryItemApp.directive:summaryItem
     * @description
     * # summaryItem
     */
    angular.module("summaryItem")
        .directive("summaryItem", function () {
            return {
                templateUrl: "views/summary-item.html",
                restrict: "E",
                transclude: true,
                controller: SummaryItemCtrl,
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                bindToController: true,
                scope: {
                    options: "=",
                    caption: "="
                }
            };
        });

    function SummaryItemCtrl($scope, $attrs) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.caption = this.caption;
        if(this.options) {
            ctrl.leftValue = this.options.leftValue;
            ctrl.rightValue = this.options.rightValue;
        }

        var readyData = {
            caption: ctrl.caption,
            leftValue: ctrl.leftValue,
            rightValue: ctrl.rightValue
        };

        $scope.$emit($attrs.id + ".ready", readyData);
    }
}(angular));
```

Comment: Can you post here the rest of your directive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your test. First of all, the event will be triggered at the first `$scope.$digest()` call. In your test, you mock the `$emit` function *after* the digest, so this will not work.

Furthermore, because your directive uses an isolate scope, `element.scope()` [does not do what you expect it to do](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). In this case, `element.scope()` will return the *original* scope of the element; `element.isolateScope()` will return the isolate scope introduced by the directive.

However, there is another way to test this. Because `$emit`-ted events bubble up to their parent scopes, you could also test that one of the parent scopes received the correct event.

Untested code:

```
  it("Should emit the ready event", inject(function ($compile) {
        var emitted = false;
        scope.$on('summaryItem.ready', function() {
          emitted = true;
        });

        element = angular.element("<summary-item id=\"summaryItem\"></summary-item>");
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        expect(emitted).toBe(true);
  }));
```

As an improvement, you can also store the event instead of just `true`, which allows you to do all kinds of `expects` on the emitted events.